# Android post request with non key pair

Tags: java, android, http, curl, post

Below is my currently working code to switch on a light with my home automation system. I am upgrading to a new system and it needs a modified post command. Currently I think this sends the key pair "lightswitch1=ON". I need it to only send "ON" but I am not sure how to do this. Below is the CURL command that works.

```
public void turnonlight() {


    String url = "http://example.com:8090/CMD";


    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MjpegActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //This code is executed if the server responds, whether or not the response contains data.
                    //The String 'response' contains the server's response.
                }
        },
            new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MjpegActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //This code is executed if there is an error.
                }
        }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MyData.put(lightswitch1 "ON"); //Add the data you'd like to send to the server.
            return MyData;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
}
```

curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "ON" "http://example.com:8090/CMD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be working with `Volley` :

```
String url = "http://example.com:8090/CMD";

StringRequest myStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "text/plain";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        String httpPostBody = "ON";
        return httpPostBody.getBytes();
    }
};
RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
myStringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
MyRequestQueue.add(myStringRequest);
```

The body is overriden by `getBody()` and the specified header with `getHeaders()`.

Comment: I am getting a "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400" error when trying to send it with your code. I used wire shark and sniffed a working request and a non working request. The one on the right is valid and the one on the left is invalid. What can I change to make the one on the left like the one on the right?

Comment: I think it is because of the content type being wrong.